# Remove dependencies for Unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I want to unit test my code without a dependency on having the back end service up and running on my google app engine.  What is the best way to achieve this without having to create my own implementation of every class like the Request factory etc.

Here is my code.  I have hacked the `Util` class to return a mock `MyRequestFactory` instance when running unit tests. This mock factory then returns mock implementation of `MyRequest`.
This in turn has mock implementations of the create,  update delete etc. methods.
Problem is I have many more entities that I need to do this with and will end up with a huge amount of mock classes.

Is there an easier way? Which mocking framework do you think would suit best?

```
MyRequestFactory requestFactory = Util.getRequestFactory(mContext,
                                                         MyRequestFactory.class);

final MyRequest request = requestFactory.myRequest();       

BookProxy bookProxy = request.create(BookProxy.class);
bookProxy.setDescription(bookDescription.getText().toString());
bookProxy.setName(bookName.getText().toString());

Log.i(TAG, "Adding book" + bookProxy.toString());

Request<bookProxy> sendRequest = request.updateBook(bookProxy);

sendRequest.fire();

bookName.setText("");
bookDescription.setText("");
```

Comment: What kinds of things have you written tests for so far?

Comment: I have implemented some very basic tests on my Activity using Robolectric. For instance test that when I click the "add book" button that a new book is sent to the server and added to the database. To allow me to test this I mocked the bookProxy class with an implementation that just keeps a local map of books and adds deletes etc from this internal map as opposed to calling the App engine service. Problem is there was far more work involved in creating the mocks than everything else put together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) for mocking as it allows spys and post execution expectation / verification.

Also, [Powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) allows things such as mocking static methods and calls to constructors.

Comment: Thanks for tip.  I have downloaded Mockito and it looks like it will save me a lot of hassle. I'm using Robolectric for my unit tests and read that it ships with Mockito pre loaded.  Anyone use Robolectric for their testing ?

Answer (score 2):

[EasyMock](http://easymock.org/) is easy to use. But if you find yourself implementing too many mock classes for unit test then this may indicate problem in your design.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a lot of luck with [JMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/). I've tried JMock before, and while it worked, it's kinda clunky. Mockito/EasyMock with the PowerMock extension are both easy to use, but they interfered with our code coverage tool.